# Rollback and Timestamp Ordering in Database

Tags: concurrency, database-theory, databases

If we use the Timestamp Ordering for concurrency control in the following scheduling:

[image]

My TA says $T_2,T_3,T_5$ is Run and $T_4,T_5$ is Rollback. I think it's false. Is there any expert who could help us?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp Ordering ensures **serializability** by serializing transactions in order of their timestamps.

The *transaction that starts earlier is assigned smaller timestamp than a transaction started later*. Assuming the given schedule shows each transaction's start. $T_{5}$ will have smallest timestamp.

So to ensure serializability the given schedule must be **[conflict serializable](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conflict-serializability/)**. In other words it must be conflict equivalent to a serial schedule(*It is a schedule in which transactions are aligned in such a way that one transaction is executed first. When the first transaction completes its cycle, then the next transaction is executed*) whose first transaction is $T_{5}$ because of smallest timestamp.

Because $Write(y)$ of $T_{5}$ **conflicts** with $Write(y)$ of $T_{3}$,  $T_{5}$ is rolled back. Now considering $T_{1}$ , $T_{2}$, $T_{3}$ , $T_{4}$, their execution is already serial with respect to each other , the order being $T_{2}$ followed by $T_{1}$, followed by $T_{3}$, followed by $T_{4}$.

Hence only transaction $T_{5}$ is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little too late, but here's my take:

> All the read and writes by t1,t2,t3,t4 are sucessfully run, since there are just 1 instructions until that point. And assuming the systems assigns the timestamp just before each transaction's first instruction.
>
> The last write(y) instruction by t5 is rejected, since the TS(T5) < W-TStamp and R-TStamp. Hence its restarted with a new time stamp.

Comment: Welcome! Late isn't a problem, since we always hope that questions here will be useful to more people than just the person who originally asked them. You've formatted most of your answer as a quotation. If it is a quotation, please acknowledge its source (e.g., with a link to the original page). If it isn't, could you edit it, to remove the visual distraction? Thanks!